# In jQuery, trying to get next-item-not-having-a-specific-class

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to get at the first not(.hidden) div after the .focus div. In this example the focus is X2, and I should get back X5, skipping X3 and X4 because they are hidden.

```
<div id='CONTAINER'>
    <div id='X1'>eks1</div>
    <div id='X2' class='focus'>eks2</div>
    <div id='X3' class='hidden'>eks3</div>
    <div id='X4' class='hidden'>eks4</div>
    <div id='X5'>eks5</div>
    <div id='X6'>eks6</div>
</div>
```

This seems like it should be a pretty simple jquery question, but I'm fairly new to this stuff.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The below statement should solve your problem.
`$("#CONTAINER").find("div.focus").nextAll("div").not(".hidden").first();`

Comment: Ok, I've finish testing and this answer is confirmed to find the first not-hidden node including when there are no not-hidden nodes. Thanks again and sorry for accepting an incorrect answer prematurely.

Comment: PS - in the end we marked up the 'not .hidden' lines with a 'notHidden' attribute so they could be identified without using the 'not' operator, which is quite slow over larger collections.

Answer (score 2):

Use the nextAll method:
http://api.jquery.com/next/

```
$('div.focus').nextAll('div:not(.hidden)').filter(':first');
```

This will find the next div after .focus that is not .hidden

Comment: this will find the next sibling _if_ it matches the selector, not the next on _that_ maches the selector.

Comment: Whats the difference between "if" and "that"? Also, "that" is not a logical operation in jQuery. What is the "that" operation? TobyODavies, your code will not find the next one, but will instead stop searching for divs when it finds a .hidden div, which will return no results in OP's example.

Comment: note that when I commented it said 'next' not 'nextAll', (and this is still what is linked). also note the `.last().next()` calls in my (still incorrect in the no-hidden case) answer will continue past the last non-hidden div. You are correct, "that" is not a logical operation in jQuery, conveniently I was writing in English, in which it is a perfectly valid word used to emphasise that next() will not continue looking past one sibling regardless of the selector given.

Answer (score 1):

try this!

```
$("#CONTAINER").find("div.focus").next('div[class!="hidden"]')
```

Comment: Wow, thanks to everyone who answered. I chose this one because it was the first one that also handled the case where no hidden divs were present.

Comment: I thought it was, but now I'm having trouble. Still checking to see if my test is contaminated. I'm thinking it won't work because 'next' only checks one node, it doesn't scan forward until a node is found.

Comment: My apologies, this one only handled the case where there were no hidden nodes, so I had to choose a different answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
$nextNotHidden = $('.focus').nextUntil(':not(.hidden)').last().next()
```

Comment: Would you mind explaining why this works and if there's a difference to the other answers?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var stop = true;
$('#CONTAINER> div.focus +div').each(function(){
    if(!$(this).hasClass('hidden') && stop) code
    else stop = false;
});
```